# Can you give an Overridden example?

Tags: java

I have created an assertion..Basically, i don't know what will be coming to verify.

It may be either text (username) or Number (Price, No. of Products available etc).

I have created two methods on the same name, whatever be the type of argument, based on the it will be called..

Is this the correct implementation of overridden concept??

```
public class U_Assertion {

    public void assertEquals(String actual, String expected) {
        // Compare Actual and Expected
        if (actual.equals(expected)) {
            System.out.println(actual + " Meets Expected " + expected);
        } else {
            System.out.println(actual + " did not Meet Expected " + expected);
        }
    }

    public void assertEquals(int actual, int expected) {
        // Compare Actual and Expected
        if (actual == expected) {
            System.out.println(actual + " Meets Expected " + expected);
        } else {
            System.out.println(actual + " did not Meet Expected " + expected);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't [*overriding*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html), it's [*overloading*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Yes, it's a correct implementation of overloading.

It's reminiscent of the methods of `System.out` (a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) object) which has different `print` & `println` methods for different data types, but which do the same thing with the values. For another example of overloading, see the [constructors of `Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#constructor.summary), which are overloaded not only for parameter type to use different input sources, but also overloaded on number of parameters, to make the `charsetName` parameter optional.

(Note that it's not strictly necessary to use overloading in your case -- the number of parameters is the same in the two methods and so you could get the same functionality by having one method whose parameters are of type `Object`:

```
public void assertEquals(Object actual, Object expected) {
    // Compare Actual and Expected
    if (actual.equals(expected)) {
        System.out.println(actual + " Meets Expected " + expected);
    } else {
        System.out.println(actual + " did not Meet Expected " + expected);
    }
}
```

That will work for arbitrary `Object`s, including `String`. It will also work for primitive types like `int`, because the values will be [boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into `Integer` objects, but there is a small extra performance cost to that. Using overloading is still useful because it avoids the boxing overhead.)

Answer (score 0):

Override concept is to redefine a method of a parent class into a child class:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("parent");
    }
}

public class ChildClass extends ParentClass{
    @Override
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("child");
    }
}

new ParentClass().method();
new ChildClass().method();
```

This will output:

```
parent
child
```